# Only wrap line when it becomes greater than 80 characters after previously being below 80

Tags: wrapping

`set tw=80` wraps lines after they reach 80 characters. Sometimes when I'm coding, writing notes, etc, I want some--but not all---lines to be longer than 80, so after it wraps, I join the line back with `J`. Later, I come back to this 85-character line, and add some more to it. The line wraps. I join it back.

This annoying workflow would be solved if Vim only wrapped lines when crossing the 80-character threshold, instead of every time I'm in insert mode typing. It seems like there should be a way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like the `t` or `l` flag in `'formatoptions'`.

```
t   Auto-wrap text using textwidth
```

```
l   Long lines are not broken in insert mode: When a line was longer than
    'textwidth' when the insert command started, Vim does not
    automatically format it.
```

The default setting is `formatoptions=tcq`. To test it out run `:set formatoption` to see if it has a `t` or `l` flag. Then run `:set formatioptions-=t` and you should be able to clack away well past your tw=80.

But I think the `l` flag is really the best option, so If the `l` flag is not present (the default) run `:set formatioptions+=l`. If the `t` flag is still set the line will wrap after passing `tw=80`, but when adding to a line already longer than 80 characters, the line will not keep wrapping automatically.

The catch to removing the `t` is vim will no longer automatically formats the other text and you have to run something like `gqip` (format inside paragraph) on the lines you want to be less than 80. There is a `c` flag that instead looks at comments specifically.  It will wrap the comment and automatically add the comment leader for you.  In conjunction with the `j` flag, when you go and hit `J` to combine the lines it will do it cleanly, meaning it will remove the comment leader from the line being appended.

run `:help fo-table` and `:help formatoptions` to find the flags and other useful info.  If `l` didn't do the trick and removing `t` is the best option, you can also add something like...

```
highlight rightMargin term=bold ctermfg=blue guifg=orange
nnoremap <localleader>h :match rightMargin /.\%>81v/
nnoremap <localleader>H :match none<cr>
```

to your vimrc.  Using this I can toggle on and off highlighting text in the 81st column onward, giving a nice unobtrusive way of knowing which lines are too long.

Edit: Changed the answer so the solution (in my last edit) was more front and center.  the `l` flag was the right answer here.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly! Might want to edit the answer so that the solution set formatoptions+=l is front and center

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I added the answer to the core post while trying to not completely change what I said originally.